# Draw a smooth string

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, gdi+

I'm trying to create a simple "Avatar" user control in WinForms that draws a string in the middle of the control. However, I can't figure out a way to draw a smooth text. Here's the code:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPaint(e);
    e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
    e.Graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
    e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
    e.Graphics.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.AntiAliasGridFit;
    e.Graphics.FillEllipse(_backgroundBrush, 0, 0, Width, Height);

    var fontSize = Width / 3 * 2;
    if(Font.Size != fontSize)
    {
        Font = new Font(_fontFamily, fontSize, _fontStyle, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
    }

    var stringSize = e.Graphics.MeasureString(_initials, Font);
    var location = new Point((int)((Size.Width - stringSize.Width) / 2),
                             (int)((Size.Height - stringSize.Height) / 2));
    
    e.Graphics.DrawString(_initials, Font, _foregroundBrush, location);
}
```

I made the font size a little bit bigger to show what I mean. In the image below, as you can see the M is broken into several parts rather than a smooth line.

[image: Result]

#### Update:

Based on the comment from @GyörgyKőszeg, I changed to `TextRenderer` and it's now looking like it should.

```
//e.Graphics.DrawString(_initials, Font, _foregroundBrush, location);
TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, _initials, Font, location, _foregroundColor);
```

[image: Desired Result]

Comment: `AntiAliasGridFit` has a very pixelated result when drawing text with GDI+ (`Graphics.DrawString`). Use pure GDI instead (`TextRenderer.DrawText`) with `ClearTypeGridFit` for the best quality.

Comment: @GyörgyKőszeg Thank you. That did it. Please add it as an answer so I can mark it as solved.

Comment: One of you two should write this up as an answer so that the next person looking to do this can find it.

Comment: You get the same effect if you set `TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.AntiAliasGridFit` (or `TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias`) and add `StringFormat.GenericTypographic` to `e.Graphics.DrawString()` (you should always specify a StringFormat when drawing text with the Graphics object) -- `Graphics.DrawString()` uses Grid fitting as the default behavior.

Comment: As a note, `SmoothingMode.HighQuality` (it's AntiAlias) only applies to the shape (the ellipse), `PixelOffsetMode` and `InterpolationMode` are irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting my comment to an answer upon request:

Use `TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit` for the desired result.
And if possible use `TextRenderer.DrawText` instead of `Graphics.DrawString` whenever possible. `TextRenderer.DrawText` uses GDI text rendering instead of GDI+ and it is the preferred way of rendering text since .NET Framework 2.0 (even by controls if `UseCompatibleTextRendering` is false).

And please also note that you should use `TextRenderer.MeasureText` instead of `Graphics.MeasureString` because they may return different sizes.

Comment: Thank you. I'll adjust the code as suggested.