# When I try to place a string using pictureBox with a transparent background, I get ugly white pixels around my string. How to solve this problem?

Tags: c#, string, picturebox, transparent, drawstring

I removed backColor from the form and added a `pictureBox`. After that I'm trying to draw a `string`. But It looks really ugly with these white pixels. Could y'all help me, please?

Here is a screenshot of the problem:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKJS5.png

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Hello World!", new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 20f), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 20, 20);
    }
}
```

Comment: I see no obvious problems with the code. I would try on another machine to see if it is a hardware issue. Or try fiddling with the [render hints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.textrenderinghint?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) to see if some setting works better.

Comment: Maybe a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73279894/5114784

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank y'all so much! I've solved the problem with:

```
e.Graphics.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.SingleBitPerPixelGridFit;
```